# Combining values of nested objects with same key in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to return an array of objects that contain the values from another object in the array that has the same `path` value.

My current array:

```
  updates: [
    {
      path: "foo",
      value: {
        currency: "USD",
      },
    },
    {
      path: "foo",
      value: {
        amount: "10000",
      },
    },
    {
      path: "bar",
      value: {
        currency: "AED",
      },
    },
    {
      path: "bar",
      value: {
        amount: "10",
      },
    },
  ]
```

Array output I'm looking for:

```
updates: [
      {
      path: "foo",
      value: {
        currency: "USD",
        amount: "10000"
      },
    },
    {
      path: "bar",
      value: {
        currency: "AED",
        amount: "10"
      },
    },

]
```

Probably a simple solution here but I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Tried using lodash:

```
var result = _(updates)
  .groupBy('path')
  .map(_.spread(_.assign))
  .value();
```

But didn't get the combined values of the nested objects, instead I got:

```
[
  { action: 'set', path: 'fellowStipend', value: { amount: '10000' } },
  {
    action: 'set',
    path: 'professionalDevelopmentAllowance',
    value: { amount: '10' }
  }
]
```

Comment: You could try using `reduce`